# Open popup and change the icon in a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, popup, icons

So, I'm trying to do a simple extension for Google Chrome.

What I'm trying to do is: When I click at the icon of my extension it will apppear (the popup.html) and change the icon to default.png.

What I've done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
        {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"default.png"});
        });

});
```

The problem is... it only shows up the popup.html... the icon doesnt change. :(

May somebody help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This sample extension on developer.chrome.com does exactly what you want.

[A browser action which changes its icon when clicked.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/set_icon_path.zip)